# How to find the :visible element using slice()

Tags: jquery

I have a form with some dropdowns and logic. I have only 1 element which can be shown between 3rd and 15th elements. I want to get that unique element which is visible. I tried `$('.className:visible').slice(3,15)` and it doesn't work. Who can help?

Comment: If there is only one visible element, `$('.className:visible')` should be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.slice()` first, before adding the `:visible` check with `:filter`.

```
$('.classname').slice(3, 15).filter(':visible')
```